# client.broadcastMessage is undefined in signalr?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to run a simple example of `signalr`, the example that i'm trying to do is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr).
I verified that `$.connection.hub.start().done` is working fine. The problem is `chat.client.broadcastMessage` is not executed as i put an alert inside it to make sure but that alert did not execute. Can any one help me to fix my problem? Here is my code:

*Chatting page.aspx*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            background-color: #99CCFF;
            border: thick solid #808080;
            padding: 20px;
            margin: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion">
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--Script references. -->
    <!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
        <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
        <script src="scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src='<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>'></script>    <!--Add script to update the page and send messages.--> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                // Html encode display name and message.
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                // Add the message to the page.
                $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            // Get the user name and store it to prepend to messages.
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            // Set initial focus to message input box.  
            $('#message').focus();
            // Start the connection.
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                $('#sendmessage').click(function () {
                    // Call the Send method on the hub. 
                    chat.server.send($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
                    // Clear text box and reset focus for next comment. 
                    $('#message').val('').focus();
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*ChatHub.cs*

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        //used to send message to all clients
        public void send(String name, String message)
        {
            Clients.All.brodcastMessage(name,message);
        }
    }
```

*Startup.cs*

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
```

**NOTE: I've figured out that, when i type chat. the dropdown menu does not show me client thus i can not call chat.client.broadcastMessage, why?**

Comment: Have you checked your console log and see if you get any errors?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen  Yes, i've used it and it does not print the text inside it. :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using addMessage instead of brodcastMessage and it works.
here is the code...

```
chat.client.addMessage = function (name, message) //script side


Clients.All.addMessage(name,message); //inside send method in the hub class
```